# How to flatten a Pandas data frame per groupby in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following Pandas data frame:

```
id  c1 c2
1   A  B
1   C  D
2   E  F
2   G  H
3   I  J
3   K  L
```

(IDs always occur in the same number respectively.)
I want to "flatten" this DF by ID (concatenate rows to have a single row by ID) to get the outcome like this:

```
1 A B C D
2 E F G H
3 I J K L
```

How can I get there? (Column names of the output DF doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`groupby` can be used, too.

```py
>>> (
     df.filter(like="c").groupby(df.id)
       .apply(lambda f: pd.Series(f.values.flatten()))
    )
    0  1  2  3
id            
1   A  B  C  D
2   E  F  G  H
3   I  J  K  L
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `pivot`:

```
(df.assign(col=df.groupby('id').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='id', columns='col')
   .sort_index(level=1, axis=1, sort_remaining=False)
   #.pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(range(d.shape[1]), axis=1))
 )
```

Output:

```
    c1 c2 c1 c2
col  0  0  1  1
id             
1    A  B  C  D
2    E  F  G  H
3    I  J  K  L
```

Alternative output (uncomment commented line):

```
    0  1  2  3
id            
1   A  B  C  D
2   E  F  G  H
3   I  J  K  L
```

Comment: How could I turn this into a "normal", one-level DF?

Comment: You can "reset" the columns, see update